# Serialization of a named class with a reference to EJB, which holds the entity manager

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, serialization, ejb, entitymanager

I use Java EE 6 with Glassfish 3.1.2.2. I have a EJB project there with stateless session beans and a WEB project with named, session scoped classes.

For example:

**Named class**

```
@Named
@SessionScoped
public class MyWebController implements Serializable {

@EJB
private MyBean myBean;
}
```

**EJB class**

```
@Stateless
public class MyBean {

@PersistenceContext
private EntityManager em;
}
```

The project is running, but when I do code analysis, I get the following message.

> Non-transient non-serializable instance field in serializable class

This Serializable class defines a non-primitive instance field which is neither transient, Serializable, or java.lang.Object, and does not appear to implement the Externalizable interface or the readObject() and writeObject() methods. Objects of this class will not be deserialized correctly if a non-Serializable object is stored in this field.

Does somebody know, who can I refactor my code to avoid this?

Answer (score 0):

Not an expert on these topics but try this one:

1) Make sure your are using the *correct* `@SessionScoped` annotation:

```
@Named
@javax.enterprise.context.SessionScoped
public class MyWebController implements Serializable {

  @EJB
  private MyBean myBean;

}
```

2) Try with EJB serializable too:

```
@Stateless
public class MyBean implements Serializable {
    ...
}
```

3) If this solution keeps broken. Try with `@Inject` instead of `@EJB`

Comment: The problem is that the stateless bean cannot be Serializable, because there is the EntityManager, which is not serializable.